# flex premature EOF

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I have written this block of code to create a compiler in flex.The editor i used was vs code 2019, when i compile the code it throws the error premature EOF at line 1.I dont know what to do, i have seen the answers to the same problem ,but they dont solve mine.

```
//------DECLARATIONS ----
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include "token.h"       

    void lexprint(char *token);
    void yyerror();
    int lineno = 1 ;  // that means that we start to count lines from 1  
'%}

 // reads only one file
/%option noyywrap 
 // shows the current inout line
%option yylineno   

 

CHARACHTER  [a-zA-Z]
DIGIT       [0-9]
NUMBER      {DIGIT}*|0
WORD        ({WORD}*|{NUMBER}*)*
VARIABLE    _?({WORD}*|{NUMBER}*)*
tab          [ \t]  




    /* -----TRANSLATION RULES  ---- */
%%


    /*KEYWORDS*/
"PROGRAM"         {lexprint(PROGRAM); return PROGRAM; } 
"FUNCTION"        {lexprint(FUNCTION); return FUNCTION;}
"VARS"           {lexprint(VARS); return VARS;}
"CHAR"           {lexprint(CHAR); return CHAR;}    
"INTEGER"         {lexprint(INTEGER); return INTEGER;}
"END_FUNCTION"     {lexprint(END_FUNCTION); return END_FUNCTION;}
"RETURN"            {lexprint(RETURN); return RETURN;}
"STARTMAIN"       {lexprint(STARTMAIN); return STARTMAIN;}
"ENDMAIN"         {lexprint(ENDMAIN); return ENDMAIN;}
"WHILE"           {lexprint(WHILE); return WHILE;}
"ENDWHILE"        {lexprint(ENDWHILE); return ENDWHILE;}
"FOR"               {lexprint(FOR); return FOR;}
"TO"                {lexprint(TO); return TO;}
"STEP"             {lexprint(STEP); return STEP;}   
"ENDFOR"             {lexprint(ENDFOR); return ENDFOR;}
"IF"                {lexprint(IF); return IF;}
"THEN"           {lexprint(THEN);return THEN;}
"ELSEIF"             {lexprint(ELSEIF); return ELSEIF;}
"ELSE"            {lexprint(ELSE); return ELSE;}
"ENDIF"          {lexprint(ENDIF); return ENDIF;}       
"SWITCH"             {lexprint(SWITCH); return SWITCH;}
"CASE"           {lexprint(CASE); return CASE;}
"DEFAULT"         {lexprint(DEFAULT); return DEFAULT;}
"ENDSWITCH"       {lexprint(ENDSWITCH); return ENDSWITCH;}
"PRINT"          {lexprint(PRINT); return PRINT;}
"BREAK"          {lexprint(BREAK); return BREAK;}

   
{VARIABLE}      {lexprint("VARIABLE\n"); return VARIABLE;}    
{NUMBER}        {lexprint("NUMBER\n"); return NUMBER;}  
{NEWLINE}       {lexprint("New Line\n"); return NEWLINE;} 
{TAB}           {}

    /*OPERATORS*/
"#"        {lexprint(hashtag); return hashtag;}
","        {lexprint(comma); return comma;}
"+"        {lexprint(syn); return syn;}
"-"        {lexprint(meion); return meion;}
"*"        {lexprint(asteriskos); return asteriskos;}
"/"        {lexprint(divison); return divison;}
"%"        {lexprint(module); return module;}
"("        {lexprint(A_parenthesi); return A_parenthesi;}
")"        {lexprint(D_parenthesi); return D_parenthesi;}
"["        {lexprint(A_aggili); return A_aggili;}
"]"        {lexprint(D_aggili); return D_aggili;}
"<"        {lexprint(A_eisagogika); return A_eisagogika;}
">"        {lexprint(D_eisagogika); return D_eisagogika;}
"!"        {lexprint(thaumastiko); return thaumastiko;}
"!="       {lexprint(diaforetiko); return diaforetiko;}
"=="       {lexprint(ison); return ison;}
"AND"      {lexprint(And); return And;}
"OR"       {lexprint(or); return or;}

"/n"       {lineno++;}
"."        {yyerror("unknown character");}




%%

  //this function prints all the token that analyzer can recognize
void lexprint(char *token){
    printf("yytext: %s\ttoken: %s\tlineno: %d\n", yytext, token_type, lineno);
}

void yyerror(char *message){
    printf("Error: \"%s\" in line %d. Token = %s\n", message, lineno, yytext);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Maybe add some sample inputs that fail.

Comment: `"/n"` : maybe you wanted `"\n"` ?

Comment: yeah thats true ,but  the error remains

Answer (score 5):

You have several errors in your Flex input.  These are at least some of them:

---

Flex recognizes C-style block comments (`/* ... */`), but it is not documented to recognize C99-style inline comments (`// ...`).

If it is *`flex`* that's throwing the error then this is probably the reason.

---

There is a stray apostrophe here:

> ```
> '%}
> ```

---

This ...

> ```
> NUMBER      {DIGIT}*|0
> ```

... matches zero-length input.  This is clearer and does not have that problem:

```
NUMBER      {DIGIT}+
```

---

This ...

> ```
> WORD        ({WORD}*|{NUMBER}*)*
> ```

... defines symbol `WORD` in terms of itself, it matches zero-length input, and it also matches digit-only sequences (but perhaps allowing the latter is intentional?).  Perhaps you meant ...

```
 WORD        ({CHARACHTER}|{NUMBER})+
```

... (misspelling of "character" copied from the original), though if indeed you meant that to match all-digit tokens then I would just write ...

```
 WORD        [a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

..., myself.

It's a bit trickier if you want to avoid matching all-digit sequences, unless you follow the traditional path of requiring the first character to be a non-digit:

```
 WORD        {CHARACHTER}[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

---

This ...

> ```
> VARIABLE    _?({WORD}*|{NUMBER}*)*
> ```

... also matches both zero-length input and digit-only input.  Supposing that neither of those is intentional, you might instead write it as

```
VARIABLE    (_|{CHARACHTER})[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

And in that case, you can just get rid of that pesky `WORD` pattern, as it is not used anywhere else.

---

Here ...

> ```
> {NEWLINE}       {lexprint("New Line\n"); return NEWLINE;}
> ```

... you attempt to use a pattern named `NEWLINE`, but no such pattern has been defined.

---

Additionally, you also have ...

> ```
> "/n"       {lineno++;}
> ```

... which appears intended to handle newlines, but instead matches the two-character sequence '/' 'n'.  If it is the built compiler that throws the error then this may be why the issue is reported as occuring on line 1 -- it is likely that this rule is never triggered, and therefore `lineno` is never incremented. Probably you wanted to combine this with the previous as:

```
\n       {lineno++; lexprint("New Line\n"); return NEWLINE;}
```

---

This ...

> ```
> "."        {yyerror("unknown character");}
> ```

... appears intended to be a fallback rule matching any character, but instead it matches only the one-character token consisting of a literal period, '.'.  You appear to want this, instead:

```
.          {yyerror("unknown character");}
```